# How to test django using test sqlite3 database instead default mysql database?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-settings

My databases in settings.py

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'mydb.com',
    'TEST': {                                        # it's not works
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

But TEST section not work.

I use this code and it works but i don't like it. Maybe there are other way in databases section describe test database?

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
```

Comment: 'TEST' doesn't support 'ENGINE': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATABASE-TEST

Answer (score 0):

create a new file your_app/test_settings.py

```
from .settings import *
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

don't forget to run migrate using your new settings

> python manage.py migrate --settings=your_app.test_settings

then finally, run your tests with your new test_settings.py

> python manage.py test --settings=your_app.test_settings